# Why refresh token has to be replaced when used?

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token

I see most of people saying when we use refresh token to exchange for a new access token, the auth server would issue a new refresh token and invalid the previous one. Refer
[OAuth Refresh Token Best Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170013/oauth-refresh-token-best-practice)

But from the OAuth website
https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/

It says the auth server can "optionally issue a new fresh token in response, or if we don't include a new refresh token, the client assumes the current refresh token will continue to be valid"

So, it looks like both options (keep or renew refresh token) are acceptable to OAuth2 standard.

My questions are:

1) Do both options are equally secure?

2) If the auth server returns a new refresh token but the client fails to receive (e.g. network error), the client has no way to re-gain access token with existing refresh token, which already invalidated. Correct?

3) If the refresh token has been leaked to someone else, both the attacker and the victim client can use it. If the auth server takes the renewal approach, then only the first one to use the refresh token can re-gain access token. So, if the victim found the refresh token is no longer valid, it may think that the refresh token has been compromised. Is this the reason for the "renewal approach"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.) Yes, that's correct.

3.) That's correct too. You can take a look at the [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-01#section-8) which discusses the refresh token regeneration. It's important mainly for public clients - the ones without client_secret, since a refresh token can be exchanged for an access token right away.

1.) Refresh token regeneration is a security feature - it shortens validity of a stolen refresh token and it enables the auth server to detect that refresh token had been compromised. So it's more secure to use it than not. But it may be more convenient for private clients not to get a new refresh token on each use - for example to prevent the refresh token loss due to network error - as you described it in point #2.

Comment: Thanks for the RFC link. It has clear guidance about re-issuing refresh tokens.